# Nodeunit sample with websockets

Tags: websocket, nodeunit

I am trying to apply the TDD principles to an application using node.js and nodeunit for the unit test. I am struggling trying to create a test case that is able to use websockets to test the application communication protocol.

I am quite new to TDD, so, is this approach correct for the TDD ?

Do you know where can I find samples to to this ?

EDIT:
I have a working sample. However I have the problem that the server takes 15 seconds in closing it self. I appreciate feedback about this code (this is WIP).

file tests/websocket.js

```
var Server = require('../tests/server.js').Server;
var wsServer = new Server();

var ioclient = require("socket.io-client");

var testCase = require('nodeunit').testCase;

exports.server = testCase({

    setUp: function(callback) {

        wsServer.initialize();

        wsServer.addEvent('connection',function(socket){
            socket.on('ping',function(data){
                socket.emit('ping', { value: 'ok' });
                socket.disconnect();
            });
        });

        callback();
    },

    tearDown: function (callback) {
        wsServer.close();
        callback();
    },


    'ping test': function(test) {
        var clientsocket = ioclient.connect( 'http://localhost:' + wsServer.getPort() );
        clientsocket.on('ping', function(data){
            test.equal('ok', data.value);
            test.done();
        });

        clientsocket.emit('ping', { pingRequest: '1' });

    },

    'another ping test': function(test) {
        var clientsocket = ioclient.connect( 'http://localhost:' + wsServer.getPort() );
        clientsocket.on('ping', function(data){
            test.equal('ok', data.value);
            test.done();
        });

        clientsocket.emit('ping', { pingRequest: '1' });

    }


});
```

file test/server.js

```
function Server() {
    this.port = 3333;
}

Server.prototype.initialize = function () {
    this.create();
}

Server.prototype.getPort= function () {
    return this.port;
}

Server.prototype.addEvent = function (name, fn) {
    this.instance.sockets.on(name, fn);
}

Server.prototype.create = function () {
    var io = require("socket.io").listen(this.port, {'log level': 1});

    //io.sockets.on('connection',);
    this.instance = io;
}

Server.prototype.close = function () {
    this.port ++;
    this.instance.server.close();
}

exports.Server = Server;
```

Comment: Found an interesting link here http://nullzzz.blogspot.com/2011/03/socketio-and-asynchronous-testing-with.html

Answer (score 1):

After reading [How does one properly shutdown socket.io / websocket-client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965733/how-does-one-properly-shutdown-socket-io-websocket-client), I found that adding the 'close timeout' and 'client store expiration' helped me solve a similar problem using the socket.io-client in a jasmin test.  On the server, add these lines (in coffee):

```
app = module.exports = express.createServer()
io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
io.set 'close timeout', 0.2
io.set 'client store expiration', 0.2
```

Then in the client, add these parameters ('reconnect' and 'force new connection'):

```
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5555', {'reconnect': false, 'force new connection': true})
```