# Node.js script doesn't quit, how to find out what functions/callbacks keep it running?

Tags: node.js

I wrote script in node.js that downloads some data and saves them to mongodb. However, after all download and save callbacks finish, the process doesn't quit.

Is there a way to see which async operations or scheduled callbacks are keeping node engine running?

Comment: share your code sample....

Comment: Ravi: I don't need specific advice, as I often encounter this problem in various contexts, I'd like to see a generic way to check for things that keep node running.

Comment: Hey @TomášKafka, please check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37243454/7006062 and let me know if that was helpful for you

Comment: Hi @AntonioNarkevich, this is wonderful! Thanks :))